# Вставка записей из другой таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Хочу вставить записи с одной таблицы в другую. Обе таблицы находятся в одной БД. Идея такова - в переменную $temp1 считывается значение,в другую переменную должна записаться запись из другой таблицы( это фамилия). В другой таблице всего 2 столбца - номер и фамилия. В логах пишется такая ошибка:

```
 PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in D:\\Server\\htdocs\\www\\add.php on line 9
```

add.php

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    $link=Connection();
    $temp1=$_POST['temp1'];
    $sql= "SELECT sname FROM names WHERE (UID='$temp1')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    $sname=mysqli_fetch_object($result);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `templog` (`temperature`,`sname`) 
            VALUES ('".$temp1."','".$sname."')"; 
    mysqli_query($link,$query);
    //var_dump(mysqli_error($link));
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Вообще это можно сделать одним запросом `insert into templog(...) select uid, sname from names where uid=?` И используйте привязываемые переменные, а не вставляйте значения непосредственно в текст запроса. Если к вас сейчас в sname окажется какая нибудь кавычка, то у вас вставка слетит с ошибкой как минимум

Answer (score 1):

Значение этой переменной (`$sname`) - объект с данными, который возвращает функция `mysql_fetch_object`, а свойства это ваши поля(свойство = значение).

Иными словами что бы получить значение нужного поля обращаться к нему нужно так `$object->fieldname`

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    $link=Connection();
    $temp1=$_POST['temp1'];
    $sql= "SELECT sname FROM names WHERE (UID='$temp1')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    $obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `templog` (`temperature`,`sname`) 
            VALUES ('".$temp1."','".$obj->sname."')"; 
    mysqli_query($link,$query);
    //var_dump(mysqli_error($link));
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо. Собственно, не подскажете, почему нельзя было напрямую вставлять значение переменной, если была использована функция mysqli_fetch_object()

Comment: Значение этой переменной - объект с данными, который возвращает функция `mysql_fetch_object`, а свойства это ваши поля(свойство = значение). Иными словами что бы получить значение нужного поля обращаться к нему нужно так `$object->fieldname`

Comment: Понятно, спасибо еще раз.

Comment: Отмечайте пожалуйста верные ответы, что бы другие могли быстро найти искомое.

Comment: @alias а вам бы желательно пояснять действия, которые делаете или которые необходимы, чтобы достичь результата.... Иначе становится неясно, что вы делали, где и зачем.

Comment: @Stanislav если вы не хотите, чтоб результатом был объект, а хотите работать с ассоциативным массивом, то пользуйтесь `mysqli_fetch_assoc` http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php   или `mysqli_fetch_array` http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php  .......вообще по ссылкам, что я привел - справа есть список, с которым можно ознакомится и посмотреть что какая функция возвращает и как работать)